# How to select dynamically generated elements

Tags: javascript

Basically, I'm trying to move list items to another list and then return them back using click event.

Just simple HTML:

```
Unchoosen: <br>
<ul id="unchosen"></ul>

Choosen: <br>
<ul id="chosen"></ul>

<script src="app.js"></script>
```

And here is `app.js`:

```
const unchosenList = document.querySelector('#unchosen');
const chosenList = document.querySelector('#chosen');

let data = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'John Doe'
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Jane Doe'
    }
];

data.forEach(e => unchosenList.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', `<li id='person'>${e.name}</li>`));

let person = document.querySelectorAll('#person');

function moveList() {
   person.forEach(e => {
     e.addEventListener('click', function() {
       this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
       chosenList.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', `<li id='chosen-person'>${this.textContent}</li>`);
     });
   });
}

if(person) {
   moveList();
}

let chosenPerson = document.querySelectorAll('#chosen-person');

function returnList() {
   chosenPerson.forEach(e => {
      e.addEventListener('click', function() {
        this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
        unchosenList.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', `<li id='person'>${this.textContent}</li>`);
      });
   });
}

if(chosenPerson) {
   returnList();
}
```

`returnList` doesn't work because `chosenPerson` was undefined, and if it does work I wonder what's gonna happen to `person`. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

When you added the event listeners, the objects didn't yet exist for unchosen-person.  When they were created, they had no event listeners.

Basically, you want to create event listeners for objects that don't exist yet.  One thing you can do is to create an event listener on the whole document, and then check the properties of the clicked element, and act accordingly:

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {

    let element = e.target;   

    if (element.id == 'person') {
        unchosenList.removeChild(element);
        chosenList.insertAdjacentHTML(
            'afterbegin', 
            `<li id='chosen-person'>${element.textContent}</li>`
        );
    }   

    else if (element.id == 'chosen-person') {
        chosenList.removeChild(element);
        unchosenList.insertAdjacentHTML(
            'afterbegin', 
            `<li id='person'>${element.textContent}</li>`
        );
    }   

});
```